# access WSDL in a docker container

Tags: web-services, docker, soap, wsdl

I built a SOAP webservice and it is working fine on my local machine. The WSDL is generated via a maven plugin from an xsd file. The WSDL can be found on my localhost: http://localhost:8080/ws/test.wsdl.
I managed to build a docker image of this webservice and it exposes on port 310.
Now my problem is: the client can't import the wsdl because it is located in the webservice container. 
My question is: what is the url the client can import the wsdl from?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running the container?  Imagine there is no such thing as “localhost”; how would you access the service?

Comment: Thank you David for your reply. 
The webservice container and the database container are ran via a docker-compose. The client is still running from the local machine and when I build it, it looks for the wsdl at the url mentioned above but obviously can't find it. 
To answer your question, I would access it via the container IP I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You have to very likely set a port binding for your container. If your container exposes port 310 you can access it, if you set a port binding rule via docker like this:

```
docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8080:310
```

This will forward any access on 127.0.0.1:8080 to the process in the container listening on port 310.